# British Citizenship

Tags: united-kingdom, citizenship

UK CITIZENSHIP

My parents and I are South African born. When I was 3 in 1961, my family left South Africa and my Dad took a civil service position in the Federation of Rhodesia and Nyasaland. He thereby obtained a British Overseas (Commonwealth) Passport and in 1967, we immigrated to the UK. The children were included on my mother’s South African passport.

Whilst in the UK, I think 1968/69, he made application at the Home Office London for separate British Travel documents for me and my Mum as I was going to proceed on a school tour into Europe. Before this was received by me however he decided to return to Africa and I am told he then my Mum was issued a UK passport with a “Right of Abode” with me again included therein.
She still travels with a UK passport with no restrictions on residence.  My younger sister also travels on a UK passport as she was born after my dad received his Commonwealth one, but she does not have the “Right of Abode”.

The question I have is would I ever be able to find out if a decision was ever taken on my application and if one was, would it be enforceable now. I currently travel on a South African passport.

Comment: This sounds like something you're better off asking of a lawyer than of random people on the internet.

Comment: You are a British citizen if in 1983 you were a Citizen of the United Kingdom and Colonies (CUKC) and you had right of abode in the UK. The question is whether you had those two things, and my guess is that you did.